# Filtering pandas series based on patterns

Tags: python, pandas, state-machine

Happy new year!

I have a quick question: Let's say I have a panda Series with 3 events like this

```
myEvents = pd.Series(['up', 'down', 'None', 'None, 'up', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up'])
```

I would like to keep the 'valid' events only: A valid event is an up followed by a down or a down followed by an up even if there is one or many 'None' between the two.
Also, all the 'up' following an 'up' should be ignored (same for consecutive 'down')

So here, by example, I would like to end up with something like

```
myEvents_filtered = pd.Series(['up', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'up'])
```

What would be the most elegant solution here ? Can I do it entirely with pandas or should I use a state machine or something like that given that I will have other similar use cases (like getting all the None following a 'down')?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This should get you your desired output. It basically drops the values of `"None"` and then drops consecutive duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd
myEvents = pd.Series(['up', 'down', 'None', 'None', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up'])
myEvents_filtered = myEvents.mask(myEvents.eq('None')).dropna()
myEvents_filtered = myEvents_filtered.loc[myEvents_filtered.shift() != myEvents_filtered]
print(myEvents_filtered)
```

As far as keeping the last task instead of the first, you would need to reverse sort the series by index, drop the first task, then reverse sort the series back to original order:

```
import pandas as pd
myEvents = pd.Series(['up', 'down', 'None', 'None', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up'])
myEvents_filtered = myEvents.mask(myEvents.eq('None')).dropna()
myEvents_filtered_rev = myEvents_filtered.iloc[::-1]
myEvents_filtered_rev = myEvents_filtered_rev.loc[myEvents_filtered_rev.shift() != myEvents_filtered_rev]
myEvents_filtered = myEvents_filtered_rev.iloc[::-1]
print(myEvents_filtered)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the element before the `'None'` and after the `'None'` are the same - try with `pd.Series(['up', 'down', 'None', 'down'])`. EDIT: works after your edit :)

Comment: Then drop the `"None"` values first like I changed it to above.

Comment: Hi Stefan thank you very much for your answer, I forgot to specify another condition in the case of multiple up or down I would like to keep the last one (because I'm using the index for another task) . With your version, the algorithm will always keep the first one do you have a workaround in mind ? many thanks

Comment: @frydayyy does my edit help?

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

1. Remove all "None" rows from the series
2. Get a column of the previous row's value
3. Filter out rows where the current is equal to the previous row's value

Code:

```
# 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
 {"my_events": my_events}
)

df = df[df["my_events" != "None"]]

# 2)
df["my_events_previous"] = df["my_events"].shift(1)

# 3)
final_result_df = df[
    df["my_events_previous"] != df["my_events"]
]

print(final_result_df["my_events"])
```

The key insight is to use [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), which can be applied to other use cases.

Comment: Hi Ben thank you very much for your answer, I forgot to specify another condition in the case of multiple up or down I would like to keep the last one (because I'm using the index for another task) . With your version, the algorithm will always keep the first one do you have a workaround in mind ? many thanks

Comment: Can you please add this additional condition into your question with an example of the input and output? That will be helpful not just for us when answering the question, but will make it easier for future users to reference this question and its answers appropriately going forward.